2D rigid body dynamics thrust vector-controlled rocket and optimal control
I have to do some calculations about the optimal control of a powered landing of a thrust vector-controlled rocket. As a start I found [1] which is almost what I need, which is the system (1) but have two problems. First, there is no table of numerical values and second in regard to the lift and drag forces it says " Note that $C_L$ and $C_D$
are functions of the Mach number $M$ and angle of attack $\alpha$ (which is
defined as the angle between the velocity vector and the nose of the
rocket)." I remember seen some formula about the relation of the coefficients and $\alpha$ but I'm not finding nor remembering how to obtain.
Can anyone point me to a reference that has the formulation (1) as in [1] just with the expanded lift and drag forces (as functions of $\alpha$) and numerical values?
Reference
[1] Liu, X "Fuel-Optimal Rocket Landing with Aerodynamic Controls"
https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/1.G003537
